# letter moves when mouse moves

Tags: html, css

I was making various buttons to try them out, and I came across a odd bug. When I move the mouse, it seems like there is a 'chance' that the first letter of the word in the first box will move to the side very slightly. I think (but am not sure) that the bug only happened when I put the text in the center of the div.

Here is a jsfiddle example:

[jsfiddle](https://goo.gl/4xdqoK)

And here is a video of what is happening:

[youtube](https://www.youtube.com/embed/uYWxVeZ0BwM)

Comment: Seems to be an issue with your browser, can't reproduce on Opera 30.0.1835.125

Comment: Also can't reproduce on Chrome, but +1 for the weird issue. What browser and version are you using, and have you tried disabling all extensions?

Comment: Could it be a font issue? Make sure you don't have the same font installed multiple times.

Comment: None of the code you have posted in the jsfiddle seems able to cause that behavior in the video, nor is it causing that behavior in any of the times I've tried. In the video there's a hover/mouseenter state on the second div that is triggering the change in the first div. I suspect that there is more code at play than you are providing, especially since the video background is purple and not black like in the jsfiddle. If you're able to reproduce the behavior using that jsfiddle, give us the OS and browser version. If you are not able to reproduce using that fiddle, then post the full code.

Comment: Post a complete code example in your question please.